# Rails Error Messages showing too much detail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a student in a programming boot camp and struggling with Rails and TDD. I have asked my professors but they have unfortunately said they are not sure what is happening and suggested I just work through it... I am coming to Stackoverflow to see if this something that has come up before.

My issue: Whenever an error is generated by rails, either from RSpec or general rails it includes a lot of extra details which make troubleshooting and TDD tedious at best. For lack of better terminology, when an error is hit it identifies every validation under the hood that caused the error to show as opposed to just saying what went wrong. For example; when I run a migrate (I purposely added an 's' creating a name error) i get the below output. Something similar is generated regardless of error.

````
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges main $rails db:migrate
== 20210405151910 CreateMechanics: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:mechanics)
   -> 0.0122s
== 20210405151910 CreateMechanics: migrated (0.0122s) =========================

== 20210405151951 CreateRides: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:rides)
   -> 0.0046s
== 20210405151951 CreateRides: migrated (0.0047s) =============================

rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateMechanicsRides
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:68:in `constantize'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:987:in `load_migration'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:982:in `migration'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:977:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1350:in `use_transaction?'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1297:in `rescue in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1285:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1263:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `each'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `block in migrate'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1363:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `migrate'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateMechanicsRides
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:68:in `constantize'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:987:in `load_migration'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:982:in `migration'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:977:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1350:in `use_transaction?'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1342:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1291:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1263:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `each'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `block in migrate'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1363:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `migrate'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/josephhaas/turing_mod_2/ic/b2-challenges/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)```
````

Comment: Its called a stack trace and is actually invaluable for troubleshooting and debugging once you learn to read them. http://railscasts.com/episodes/24-the-stack-trace

Comment: The reason you are getting a missing constant error here is most likely that the file name of your migration does not match the name of of the class contained in it. Rails removes the timestamp and tries to initialize an instance of the class that it derives by calling `String#classify` on `20210405194112_create_mechanics_rides.rb` -> `MechanicsRides`. This really has absolutely nothing to do with test driven development.

Comment: If you want to use a `has_many through:` association use `rails g model MechanicRides mechanic:belongs_to ride:belongs_to`. For `has_and_ belongs_to_many` use `rails g migration create_mechanics_rides_join_table mechanics rides`. The former is usually preferable though.

Comment: @max thank you for responding and how to fix, I actually purposely broke it to generate an error log. FYI you nailed how I broke it :) 

Is there a way to set the stack trace to not default on? I understand how to do a trace, but I am always getting a full stack even when I would rather just see the basic error message

Comment: You can use[ backtrace silencers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html) to filter the backtrace. Note that exceptions are not really part of the red/green cycle of TDD - when you get an exception it's not just a test failure but rather a more exceptional issue. The proper flow should really be - fix exception and get to red - then implementent the feature and get to green.